# How do I enter chinese names in Address Book?

Tags: contacts, internationalization, language, sort

[Chinese names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_name) are quite elaborate and quite different from the "standard American name" that the Mac Address Book is based on.

Notably I'm looking for a good way to

- Store a person's *Chinese name* – an alias written in Chinese characters.
- Store a person's western alias in addition to their transliterated Chinese name.
- Minimize duplicate contact issues (via sync and social network imports) that can't easily be de-duplicated through the `Look for Duplicates...` command.

This is somewhat related to [How do I enter Dutch names in Address Book?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/how-do-i-enter-dutch-names-in-address-book) but for people who wants to file details of their PRC and Chinese diaspora contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Keyboard Preference Pane.There are four tabs there. Select Input Sources. Click the + button located at the bottom of the language sidebar. Select Chinese language from there. You can also switch languages with the "Show input menu in the menu bar".

[image: Keyboard Language Preferences]

Comment: This doesn't say which field to enter it to.

Answer (score 0):

I normally store the western aliases as "nickname".

Comment: Do you normally write Chinese characters in your computer?